# Span element with width and line break before

Tags: html, css

I am receiving content from an API that includes several span elements followed by unmarked text.

Example:

```
<span>1</span> Some text. <span>2</span> Some text.
```

I want the spans to have a set width and a line break before.

Example:

```
 1 Some text.

 2 Some text.
```

"display: block" on the spans allows the width property but also creates a break after each span.

"display: inline-block" allows for the width property but I cannot figure out how to create a line break before.

Leaving the spans as "display: inline" allows for the line break before each span (using ::before content). However, you cannot designate a width property for inline elements (as far as I have seen).

Comment: I'm not sure I see an actual question here.  From what I can tell, option number three (_"display: inline" does not allow the width property, but I can produce the break with psuedo before content._) accomplishes what you require.  What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a wrapper for this content you can make it a grid container and easily achieve what you want:

```css
.wrapper {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:30px 1fr;
}

span {
 text-align:center;
 outline:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<span>1</span> Some text. <span>2</span> Some text.
</div>
```

Another idea with flexbox and `display:contents` (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents)

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  padding-left:10px;
}

span {
 display:contents;
 outline:1px solid green;
}
/*create line break*/
span:before {
  content:"";
  flex-basis:100%;
}

/*control the width*/
span:after {
  content:"";
  width:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<span>1</span> Some text. <span>2</span> Some text.
</div>
```

Here is also another way using counter:

```css
body {
 counter-reset: count;
}

span {
  counter-increment: count;
  font-size:0; /*remove default content*/
}
/*add line break*/
span::before {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}

/*add content with counter*/
span::after {
  content:counter(count);
  font-size:initial;
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px; /*control the width*/
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<span>1</span> Some text. <span>2</span> Some text.
```

Answer (score 5):

To achieve expected result, use below option of content and white-space

```css
span::before {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<span>1</span> Some text. <span>2</span> Some text.
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/RdmxrR